# Trying to save data in localStorage

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my React app, after fetching some data from the API, I'm trying to store the data in localStorage as well as my redux store. I keep getting the

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
>   actions.

Here's my code:

```
export const setDataInStore = (myData) => {

    return { 
        type: types.SET_MY_DATA,
        myData
    };
}

const setDataInLocalStorage = (myData) => {

        window.localStorage.myData = myData;
}

export const getMyData = () => {

    return (dispatch) => fetch('/api/mydata', fetchOptionsGet())
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                parseJSON(response)
                    .then(myData => {

                        dispatch(setDataInStore(myData));
                        dispatch(setDataInLocalStorage(myData));
                    })
            } else {
                // Handle error
            }
        })
}
```

The issue is with `setDataInLocalStorage` function. When I put `debuggers`, I see that I'm coming into `setDataInLocalStorage` and `myData` is populated by the API call.

What am I doing wrong there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dispatch` expects an action object to be returned. In this case `setDataInLocalStorage` doesn't return an action for `dispatch` to do anything with.

Since we only want to set localstorage, we can change the dispatch lines to this to:

```
dispatch(setDataInStore(myData));
setDataInLocalStorage(myData);
```

We treat setDataInLocalStorage() as a regular function being called.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around? `setDataInStore` does expect an action object which then sends the request to the reducer. The function that does not expect an action object is the `setDataInLocalStorage`.

Comment: Great catch, you're 100% right. Got mixed up writing the response, I'll update it!

Comment: The problem I'm still having is that `myData` is NOT being stored in `localStorage`. I hit the `setDataInLocalStorage` and `myData` is there as well. The line seems to execute fine but next time I check `localStorage`, my data is not there. Any idea why the data is not being stored in `localStorage`?

Comment: localStorage cannot be updated through plain assignment `window.localStorage.myData = myData;`. Storage interfaces use the [setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) method to add items to storage.  (eg. `localStorage.setItem("myData", myData);`

Comment: Good point but still not storing the data. One thing interesting is that after the line `window.localStorage.setItem("myData", myData);` when I check what's in `localStorage`, I see `localStorage.myData: [object, object]`. I don't see the actual object with my values in it. I wonder if this has anything to do with `promises`. I do see my object with values when i hit the `setDataInLocalStorage` function though.

Comment: Something to note, localStorage/sessionStorage cannot store objects as values. If it's the case where `myData` is an `object`, we'll have to convert it to a string first. One way to do this is `localStorage.setItem("myData", JSON.stringify(myData));` Then when it's time to read that data out, use `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myData"));` `JSON.parse()` can throw an exception so wrapping it in a `try/catch` would be useful.